# React serverside rendering event handlers not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm server side rendering React with React-Router.
I've created a simple boilerplate, but the event handler aren't fired in the application.

I've added a `onClick` on the `<button>` inside `shared/components/App.js`, but it doesn't log anything when I click on it. What could be wrong here?

The repository can be found at: https://github.com/guidsen/universal-react-boilerplate/tree/feature/react-router-with-redux

Rendered HTML:

```
<div id="root">
  <div data-reactid=".rx2jppj2f4" data-react-checksum="-165530220">
    <div data-reactid=".rx2jppj2f4.$1">
      <span data-reactid=".rx2jppj2f4.$1.0">Book 1</span>
      <span data-reactid=".rx2jppj2f4.$1.1"> - Read by </span>
      <span data-reactid=".rx2jppj2f4.$1.2">2</span>
      <span data-reactid=".rx2jppj2f4.$1.3"> people.</span>
      <button data-reactid=".rx2jppj2f4.$1.4">Add reader</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you accidentally turn your JavaScript off? Your component works as it should http://jsbin.com/ceborupuni/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Are you getting the console.log as well when you click the button?

Comment: I see, really strange. Doesn't console.log on my end :/

Comment: @limelights might have something to do with serverside rendering..

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Are you getting anything rendered at all?

Comment: @limelights I've modified my question and added html output

Comment: Instead of adding html it would be good to look at your components and routes~!

Comment: @limelights still couldnt make it work